# Phonegap android contacts with avatar resize

Tags: android, cordova, contacts, image-resizing

I create a app to edit Android Phone contact (Android 4) using phonegap (version 2.5). Everything okay but a problem with contact avatar. (Avatar is load from phone library, get avatar as URI)

If choose a **large avatar** ( larger than 1 MB ), Contact can not be updated. So I try auto re-size all chosen avatar to 400x400 pixel. As logcat, I can see it write to **/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/{package_name}/cache/resize.jpg** but error occur when try to save

```
E/ContactsAccessor(28252): /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/{package_name}/cache/resize.jpg?1374660687484: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ContactsAccessor(10624): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.lunextelecom.m/cache/resize.jpg?1374718026949: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ContactsAccessor(10624):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
E/ContactsAccessor(10624):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
E/ContactsAccessor(10624):  at libcore.net.url.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:82)
...
```

I check using a file explorer, the image **existed** there. Don't know why it can read it.

I also check and has **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission setup

Please help me to resoleve this or any other solution to **update phone contact** if user choose a **large avatar**. Thanks alot.

Here is my get image code

```
var options =   {   
    quality: 75,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: 0,      // 0:Photo Library, 1=Camera, 2=Saved Photo Album
    encodingType: 0,     // 0=JPG 1=PNG
    targetWidth: 400,
    targetHeight: 400
};

navigator.camera.getPicture( function(imageData) {
    image_ctl.setSrc(imageData);
    console.log('AVARTA IMG GET'); }, function() {
    app.showAlert('Error taking picture', 'Error'); }, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not load image by navigator.camera.getPicture.
This feature can be usefull only for open dialog for get image from gallery or capture photo from camera.
So you can't transmit imagefile data to this function. I know its annoying.

It showed in documentation:

navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, [ cameraOptions ] );

Description

The camera.getPicture function opens the device's default camera application that allows users to snap pictures. This behavior occurs by default, when Camera.sourceType equals Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA. Once the user snaps the photo, the camera application closes and the application is restored.

If Camera.sourceType is Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY or Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM, then a dialog displays that allows users to select an existing image. The camera.getPicture function returns a CameraPopoverHandle object, which can be used to reposition the image selection dialog, for example, when the device orientation changes.